# Show content if parent page has children

Tags: php, conditional-tags, child-pages

Using this piece of code you can show content depending if it's a child-page or not:

```
<?php
global $post;

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) : ?>
This is a child-page.

<?php else : ?>
This is a parent-page.

<?php endif; ?>
```

But I would like to add one more statement, so that I could have different content if it's a parent-page that has a child, or a parent-page that hasn't. Would something like this below work? If yes, what would "XXX" be?

```
<?php
global $post;

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) : ?>
This is a child-page.

<?php elseif ( is_page() && XXX ) : ?>
This is a parent-page (with one or more children)

<?php else : ?>
This is a parent page without children.

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using this code:

```
<?php
global $post;
$children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) );

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) : ?>
This is a child-page.

<?php elseif ( is_page() && count( $children ) > 0 ) : ?>
This is a parent-page (with one or more children)

<?php else : ?>
This is a parent page without children.

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also create your own conditional tag.
In **functions.php** add:

```
function my_is_parent() {
    global $post;

    $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
    if( count( $children ) > 0 ) {
        $parent = true;
    }

    return $parent;
}
```

And in your IF instead of XXX add: `my_is_parent()`

You could of course name it something else instead of "my_is_parent" if you want. Not sure on this part though, but I guess that it´s not really feature proof to use "is_parent" if it gets included in core one day.

Comment: Shouldn't this return $parent = true, a boolean value rather than text?

Comment: @Trevor yes you are right. Though it works with the text value as well, but I updated this 3 years old answer now :)

Comment: Still a valid answer 7 years later.

Answer (score 0):

you can achive that with using

```
global $post;

$args = array (
    'parent' => $post->ID
);

$children = get_pages( $args );

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) : ?>
This is a child-page.

<?php elseif ( is_page() && count( $children ) > 0 ) : ?>
This is a parent-page (with one or more children)

<?php else : ?>
This is a parent page without children.

<?php endif; ?>
```

and using `count( $children ) > 0` instead of your XXX

Comment: Could you show the full code? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @nicolas, filled in the full code for you.